# Insert image in Bootstrap Popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I am using [Bootstrap Popver](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers). I have inserted some data in the popover and want to insert a image as well. This is what I have tried.

Code:

```
var img = '<div id = "image"><img src = "http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/71832000/jpg/_71832498_71825880.jpg" /></div>';
var button = "<button title = " + obj.hostname + "&#44;&#32;" + gpu.toUpperCase() +
        " data-content = \"" + metric_name[metric] + ":&#32;" + display_val + img + "\"" +
        " data-id=\"" + detailed_summary + "\"" +
        " data-text = \"" + obj.hostname + ", " + gpu.toUpperCase() + ", " + metric_name[metric] + ":&#32;" + display_val + "\"" +
        " class=\"btn " + button_state + " gpu btn-lg open-InfoModal\"" +
        " data-toggle=\"modal\" " +
        " data-html=\"true\" " +
        " rel=\"popover\" " +
        " data-target=\"#hostInfo\" " +
        " href=\"#infoModal\"></button>";
```

Initialisation:

```
$('button').popover({
            trigger: "hover",
            placement: get_popover_placement,
            html: true
});
```

I have seen some examples on Stack Overflow, but it didn't work for me as I want to insert it inside the button declaration.

Answer (score 3):

Make use of the `content` setting of the popover function:

```
$('button').popover({
            trigger: "hover",
            placement: get_popover_placement,
            html: true,
            content: img //loads the image inside the popover container
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aZLCv/)**

Comment: I know I could do it, and it was working with this, but I have some variables which I also need to show along with the content. That's why I said I have to use it inside the button.

Comment: @user2798227 As in a button image? If yes, is the variable dynamic and always comes with the `<div>`?

Comment: Nope, As in button with a data + image in popover and modal on click.  I have solved this, Thanks for your help. I will post my answer here.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it using the code below.

```
   button = "<button title = " + obj.hostname + "&#44;&#32;" + gpu.toUpperCase() +
           " data-content = \"" + returnPOContent(metric_name[metric], display_val) + "\"" +
       //" data-content = \"" + metric_name[metric] + ":&#32;" + display_val + "\"" +
        " data-id=\"" + detailed_summary + "\"" +
        " data-text = \"" + obj.hostname + ", " + gpu.toUpperCase() + ", " + metric_name[metric] + ":&#32;" + display_val + "\"" +
        " class=\"btn " + button_state + " gpu btn-lg open-InfoModal\"" +
        " data-toggle=\"modal\" " +
        " data-html=\"true\" " +
        " rel=\"popover\" " +
        " data-target=\"#hostInfo\" " +
        " href=\"#infoModal\"></button>";

function returnPOContent(mName, dVal) {
    var popOverContent = mName + ": " +dVal+"</br><div id='test'><img src='http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/71832000/jpg/_71832498_71825880.jpg'/></div>"; 

    return popOverContent;
}

    $("button").popover({
            trigger: "hover",
            placement: get_popover_placement,
            html: true
      });
```